# Resolve Python linting errors for dynamically loaded modules

Tags: python, python-import, pylint

Consider following project structure that uses nested modules:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── test.py

3 directories, 4 files
```

Content of `test.py` file:

```python
from a.b.c import foo

print(foo())
```

Content of `a/b/c/__init__.py`:

```python
def foo():
    return "Hello world"
```

I'd like to omit `b` when importing things and use `from a.c import foo` in `test.py`. This is because I want to organize the code internally in separate subdirectories while allowing files in the root directory to import everything using same base import path. I can achieve that by adding following code to the `a/__init__.py`:

```python
import importlib
import sys

importlib.import_module("a.b.c")
sys.modules["a.c"] = sys.modules["a.b.c"]
```

It works and when I call `python test.py` having `from a.c import foo` in it I can see expected `Hello world` output. However various Python tools and linters hate this. If I try to run `pylint` on `test.py` I can see it reporting import errors:

```
$ pylint test.py
************* Module test
test.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
test.py:1:0: E0401: Unable to import 'a.c' (import-error)
test.py:1:0: E0611: No name 'c' in module 'a' (no-name-in-module)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

Similarly, if I try to open this in PyCharm it reports errors in the import line:

```
Cannot find reference 'c' in '__init__.py' 
Unresolved reference 'foo'
```

How can I make these tools understand my intent of treating `c` module as it were inside `a` directory? I know I can disable various lints placing comments such as `# pylint: disable=E0401` in `test.py` but that's not portable (what if someone uses a different linter in some different IDE...?) and hides the problem instead of resolving it. I'd also hate to copy these into every `.py` file in the root directory.

Or perhaps it's impossible to achieve and I have just always specify a proper full path...?

Comment: Create a file `a/c.py` that imports everything you want. Some libraries do this to have "public" modules for exporting the API from the "private" (`_` prefix) modules with the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change `__init__.py` in `a` to import all the necessary submodules and make it accessible. You could base your ideas on the following `__init__.py` placed in `a`.

```
import b.c as c
```

Then you can access the module in `test.py` as follows:

```
import a
a.c.foo()
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a `c.py` in `a` as ivvija suggests.

c.py:

```
from b.c import *
```

For this you just need to make sure you aren't redefining `__all__` in `a/b/c/__init__.py` and if you are make sure to add all the needed function like `__all__ = ["foo"]`